# How do I paint a javax.swing.ImageIcon into a JavaFX .fxml rendered User Interface?

Tags: java, swing, javafx-8, fxml

I am developing a **JavaFX** rich client that uses legacy resource providers. One such provided resource is a `javax.swing.ImageIcon`. I have to paint that icon inside a details dialog that is rendered from a JavaFX .fxml file.

The way I found to work was to paint the `ImageIcon` into a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` using the `ImageIcon.paintIcon()` method with a `java.awt.Graphics` from `BufferedImage.createGraphics()`. From that `BufferedImage`, `javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils.toFXImage()` gives a `javafx.scene.image.WritableImage` that can be placed in the `ImageView` of the .fxml.

Here is the code of the transforming method, based on some other solutions viewed here in StackOverflow:

```
private javafx.scene.image.Image atonIcon2ImageConverter(ImageIcon icon) {
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            icon.getIconWidth(),
            icon.getIconHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
    // paint the Icon to the BufferedImage.
    icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
    g.dispose();
    return SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bi.getSubimage(0, 1, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight()-1), null);
}
```

Although this solution works, it appears to me quite convoluted and I would like some expert opinion on how it could be made more straightforward. With JavaFX being the successor of Swing, I see quite possible that there is a simpler way to place a Swing `ImageIcon` inside a JavaFX .fxml file (the `ImageIcon`is given, but the `ImageView` can be challenged).

## Edit: my solution.

After playing around and mixing different comments and solutions, here is what I came out with for my real system implementation. It definitely is a very particular environment (the `ImageIcon` has a Swing `ToolkitImage` inside), so it might not be applicable to many:

```
private javafx.scene.image.Image atonIcon2ImageConverter(ImageIcon icon) {
    BufferedImage bi = ((sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage)imageIcon.getImage()).getBufferedImage();
    return SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bi, null);
}
```

Comment: *"With JavaFX being the successor of Swing"* It is, though? I've heard that said on occasions by programmers, but never as an official announcement by (Sun or) Oracle.

Comment: @AndrewThompson you are exactly in the same page as I am. I have read it in a couple of places in the context that "JavaFX 2 was not considered by the mainstream public as successor for Swing, but the arrival of JavaFX 8 did provide a good candidate." I'm new to JavaFX, so I will not make absolute statements. My hope was to trick anyone "very close to the JavaFX development" to answer that it was not the case or that it is and this particular problem is solved as such and such.

Comment: Excellent response. ;) OK now back to it. Firstly *why* do you need to convert a Swing icon to a Java-FX icon? Second, if Java-FX has an inbuilt icon that accepts an input stream containing an image, why not turn the AWT based `BufferedImage` into a stream?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: To your first question, my original question is the answer: I need to display the ImageIcon I get from a legacy system inside a .fxml rendered GUI; I am not sure how it should be done, but the pipeline I mentioned is the one I found that works. To you second question: "that idea I have yet to try." It is now in my queue ---and it is for my free time since my ugly solution works and has been accepted by the project.

Comment: Not trying to make a novel out of this, but the latest project-related development is that a veteran looked at it and pointed out that the `ImageIcon` is not a hard requirement. Then fiddled a little bit around and found the resource from where the image can be read. Problem solved. Although I am still interested int the improvement of the original problem --with `ImageIcon` as starting point.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I've been looking around a bit and found out the `javafx.scene.image.Image` constructor that takes an `InputStream` as parameter... but I am not sure you were reffering to this one in your comment. Also I failed to find how to stream the `ImageIcon`; probably impaired by lack of experience in Java8 "new" features.

Comment: My suggestion of using a stream is no less (and probably more) of a hack than your original method. But `ImageIO` can `write` to a stream, which might be a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, from which a `byte[]` can be obtained, to immediately turn into a `ByteArrayInputStream` for the.. I *did" remember to mention 'more of a hack', didn't I? ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson  Initially I thought you were talking about _stream pipelines_ in the line of Java8 _streams_.
I couldn't find the types matching so I could do the `javafx.scene.image.Image fxImage = new javafx.scene.image.Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageIcon.getImage().somethingHere())` so I give up.

Comment: *"Initially I thought you were talking about stream pipelines"* Oh, it is probably an option. To be honest, I don't do much I/O. Or rather, the I/O I need was implemented a *loooong* time ago. I've not really been keeping up with the latest I/O APIs. Sorry, just realized my comments here have been more 'noise' than 'signal'. My bad.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: But the idea was appealing and got me trying different things. I definitely found quite some "signal" in your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon;
Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
BufferedImage bufferedImage = (BufferedImage) image;
```

or combinded

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = (BufferedImage) imageIcon.getImage();
```

Whether this works or not depends on how the ImageIcons are constructed in your legacy code. Here is a working example. It also contains the commented out variant which does not work.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class ImageIconTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ImageIcon imageIcon = createImageIcon("/DukeCheers.png", "DukeCheers");

        BufferedImage bufferedImage = (BufferedImage)imageIcon.getImage();

        System.out.println("done");
    }

    private static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path, String description) throws IOException {
        java.net.URL imgURL = ImageIconTest.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {

            // This does not work.
            // return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);

            // This works.
            return new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(imgURL), description);

        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It works. Now the whole thing remains reduced to two lines: `BufferedImage bi = ((sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage)imageIcon.getImage()).getBufferedImage();` and `javafx.scene.image.Image img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bi.getSubimage(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight()), null);` Thanks for the tip. You may rewrite the answer if you find it worth your while.